# Python Azure opentelemetry - inbound requests not getting logged

Tags: python, fastapi, open-telemetry, azure-sdk-python, azure-monitor

I followed the instructions and the sample project here: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Python/blob/05a8b1dd3556ab5e7c268c22ee30a365eaf5ec7a/azure-monitor-opentelemetry/samples/tracing/http_fastapi.py#L15. I set up my app insights account and I can see exceptions and dependencies properly getting logged.

However, **the requests table** is not getting populated.. Based on the link above, requests to my FastAPI should automatically be populated. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I was also quite confused as to many things which are explained in Azure Documentation do not work as expected. This was one of them.

You will have to add a line to import FastAPIInstrumentor and instrument your app to see the requests coming into your app-insights.

`from opentelemetry.instrumentation.fastapi import FastAPIInstrumentor FastAPIInstrumentor.instrument_app(app)`

If this does not help, you might have to add a few more dependencies, which will instrument your requests.

For further info, check this out:
[FastAPI intrumentor](https://opentelemetry-python-contrib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/instrumentation/fastapi/fastapi.html)